# Incorrect credentials with Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, token, restful-authentication

I'm trying to set up token authentication with the Django Rest Framework. I'm currently writing some tests to see if I can get a token returned for a user. Below is the code for the unit test (which is inside of a test case).

```
def test_create_valid_request(self):
    u = User.objects.create(username='test1', password='thisis8chars')
    Token.objects.create(user=u)

    # these assertions all pass
    self.assertEqual(User.objects.get(username='test1'), u)
    self.assertEqual(u.username, 'test1')
    self.assertEqual(u.password, 'thisis8chars')

    data = {'username': 'test1', 'password': 'thisis8chars'}
    url = "/api-token-auth/"

    response = self.client.post(url, data, format="json")
    print response.status_code
    print response.content
```

This  prints:

```
400
{"non_field_errors":["Unable to log in with provided credentials."]}
```

I understand that there must be something wrong with my credentials, but I can't see it. I create a user, tests its attributes, and make a post request to retrieve the token. I've manually tested this on the Django development server with `httpie`, and it works and returns the token. Any ideas what the problem could be? Is this a problem with my testing setup? If so, what?

I can post/describe more code if necessary.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Okay so the error was very simple: I wanted `User.objects.create_user` rather than `User.objects.create`.

The password that I was trying to use with my code above was problematic because it wasn't hashed or salted, and because Django doesn't store or send plain-text passwords, me sending the plain-text password was resulting in a bad credentials error.

Answer (score 1):

As you've already stated, you need to use `User.objects.create_user`.

To add to this, if you already have a User object instantiated and want to change their password you'll need to call the `user.set_password(raw_password)` method.